# Get index of empty space returns wrong value

Tags: javascript, jquery

In JS I have a text line and I want to get the index of the first occurrence of an empty space.

For example, this is my line:

```
gram somethin b
```

And this is my code:

```
index = line.indexOf(" ");
if (index == -1)
    index = line.indexOf("\u00a0");
```

The problem here is that the result of the code is 13, but it should be 4.

Why doesnt it recognize the empty space after 'gram' as empty space? How can I check?

Comment: Can you make a fiddle because with what we see we can only conclude you fail at displaying the index ?

Comment: What you posted worksforme. Maybe in your actual code it's not a blank, but some other whitespace? then use `line.search(/\s/)`

Comment: @Bergi How many whitespaces are there?

Comment: @petko_stankoski: I don't know? It's your string. I can see two in what you posted.

Comment: @petko_stankoski Not sure why you need the position of the very first whitespace character, however, I guess you're better off using regular expressions in such cases. For example, `line.match(/[^\s]+/)[0]` would return the first word (continuous sequence of non-space chars) in a string. For more info about RegEx, visit **http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html**.

Answer (score 1):

Also can Use Here ASCII character

ASCII code 32 for Space

```
var line = "gram somethin b";
var FirstSpaceIndex;

for (var i = 0; i < line.length; i++) 
{
    if(line.charCodeAt(i) ==  32)
    {
        FirstSpaceIndex = i;
        break;
    }
}

alert(FirstSpaceIndex);
```